# On mongoimport, can I easily map a field to _id on json import?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I need to import a dataset that looks like the similar (abbreviated) dataset.

```
[
  {
    "itemId": 1,
    "name": "Item",
    "qty": "10"
  },
  ...
]
```

The tricky part is that doing inserts indefinitely will not raise any exception, but the `itemId` field would represent a valid identifier equivalent to `_id` field if it could be accepted as such.

Does any option akin to `--idField itemId` exists?

Comment: I don't think that can be done out of the box but unless you need to do that on a regular basis you could `mongoimport` your data accepting the autogenerated `_id` values, then use an aggregation query like `$project: { _id: nameId }` followed by an `$out` stage to write the modified documents into a new collection.